# error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Алина\brain.jpg") #считали файл
img1 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Алина\brain.jpg")
img1.show()
imggray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #задали перекраску файла
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imggray,127,255,0) #перекрасили файл
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #ищем контуры и складируем их в переменную contours

cnt = contours[4] #-1 - все контуры, тут задаем кол-во контуров
img = cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3) #отрисовываем контуры поверх изображения

cv2.imshow('contours', img) #вот тут он должен вывести изобрж с контурами, но все почему-то виснет. Лучше это не трогать
```

После строки imggray выдает ошибку error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: Решено вот этим куском кода:
def cv_imread(file_path):
    cv_img=cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(file_path, dtype=np.uint8),-1)
    return cv_img
file_path = r'C:\Users\Алина\brain.jpg'
img = cv_imread(file_path)